# I can't access the Voyager admin panel after installing

Tags: laravel, voyager

I tried hard-coding an admin panel in my Laravel project only to find out about Voyager.

So I installed voyager on my project (the admin panel files are still there).

However, every time I test it out by going to mydomain.test/dashboard/login , it keeps going back to my site's index page.

Do you think it has something to do with my hardcoded admin panel files? The files are inside the project folder prior to installing voyager.

Or I'm missing something here?

I changed the route's prefix into 'dashboard' instead of 'admin' because my hardcoded admin panel is using 'admin'.

```php
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('front');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
        Voyager::routes();
    });
```

I want to access the Voyager admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE]
I have finally resolved this issue by simply adding a new user and grant admin access to it.

Answer (score 0):

your url it's not good.
try "mydomain.test/admin/login" or "mydomain.test/admin"

be careful, create the first user from the command line.

Comment: I did try that url but it's still redirecting me back to the site's index page.

Comment: so it is due to the fact that the user does not have access. you have to create an admin and look at the permissions you gave him.

Comment: that actually fixed the problem. Thank you!